# what is the eslint config "plugins" value used for?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint, eslint-plugin

While configuring eslint I stumbled over the fact, that some preconfigured plugins suggest setting the `"plugins" : []` value inside my config ([typescript](https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started)), while other plugins don't suggest it ([stencil](https://github.com/stencil-community/stencil-eslint)).

On the prementioned Typescripts plugin documentation, I can read

> plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'] tells ESLint to load the
> @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin package as a plugin.
>
> - This allows you to use typescript-eslint's rules within your codebase.

What does this mean? the `--print-config` flag produces the same config, whether I provide the plugins or not and the linting also works perfectly without them. So why would I want to set this additional value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reading through the documentation of the [a11y plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y), I found this statement:

> As you are extending our configuration, you can omit "plugins":
> ["jsx-a11y"] from your .eslintrc configuration file.

This seems to be the answer. Using the recommended ruleset does internally add the plugin to the plugins list of eslint. I verified this for the three linked plugins of this QA post.